# Boto 3 DynamoDB update table api not raising provisioning of the table?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, aws-glue

Hi Iam having an issue with boto3 update table api when I am trying to update the provisioning of my table. The table does get the event to update the provisioning but instead of raising the provisioning to the level that I want it sets its to the default value of the table.

here is my code that I am using:

```
import boto3

dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

resp = dynamodb_client.update_table(
            TableName='my_table',
            ProvisionedThroughput={
                'ReadCapacityUnits': 5,
                'WriteCapacityUnits': 5000,
            }
        )

    print(str(resp))
```

currently my table is set to auto scale

read provision: 5

write provision: 10

every time that I call my glue python job which contains this code. No error is given and when I check the scaling activities of the table it always says changed the write capacity to 10. That is not the value that I passed in though? The regions are the same and I am able to write to this table?

what could be going on?

thank you

Comment: How often are you trying to change the capacity? The docs state "DynamoDB doesn't allow you to increase provisioned capacity very rapidly"

Comment: Hi am only trying to raise it 1 time per day. Ive been testing my method out a bit today so ive probably tried to raise about 10 times today. I think the error could be that Im trying to increase it from 5 to 5000 in one go? maybe increase it gradually. When I tried to increase it to 500 it worked but for some reason not 1000 or 5000. Its weird because when I go to the table directly I can increase it to 5000 really quickly but not through code

Comment: there seems to be a problem. I am able to raise it to something lower like 500 but almost right away dynamodb scales the writing back down to default after only about 2min after updating the table

Comment: Check the response from Dynamodb in the cloudwatch logs of the glue job maybe the request failed